# How do i change the color of the font for the current directory in M-x term?

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp, color-scheme

Normally when i need to change the color of a certain element in emacs, i would do a M-x describe-face which will eventually bring up a customize buffer to change it. In the emacs term, It seems like i dont have the ability to enter the minibuffer to input that command. How do I figure out which variable to change?

Heres a picture, to make things a bit more clear:

[http://imgur.com/jXHNC.png](https://imgur.com/jXHNC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the term you get to by doing `M-x term`? If so, you're probably not doing `C-c C-j` to enter line-run mode before you try to do `M-x describe-face`.

Comment: That got me a bit further, i was able to run the describe-face command while i was over the text of the text whose color I want to change but all it returned was that it was the default face (in customize it wasnt the color i was looking to change). I think this may have to do with ansi color codes.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the color is being set by the shell, and not by emacs (which then considers it to be displayed in the default face). If you're using bash, the prompt is controlled using the environment variable `PS1`, so try `export PS1="\u@\h$ "` to change the prompt to "username@host $ " with no coloring. If the change takes effect you can google for `shell prompt color` and find plenty of tutorials about what can be set, or doing the same for a different shell.